# Projective dimension of the residue field of a noetherian local ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.

> Is it true that the projective dimension of $R/\mathfrak m$ is finite knowing that its injective dimension is finite? If yes, why?!?

I would need this to prove something else but I'm not sure I can use it.
Can you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the "global dimension theorem" will help. cf. Weibel... haven't thought about this though, but that's just where I'd look first.

Answer (score 4):

If $\operatorname {injdim} (k)\lt \infty$, then $R$ is regular : this is stated as exercise 3.1.26 of Bruns-Herzog's [Cohen-Macaulay rings](http://books.google.fr/books?id=LF6CbQk9uScC&pg=PA317&dq=bruns-herzog&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=DbR0T5qBFKGk0QWKxqEM&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=bruns-herzog&f=false).
From this follows from Serre's theorem that $R$ has finite global dimension and then of course this implies that $k$, like all $R$-modules, has finite projective dimension.

Comment: No need to use Serre's Theorem: use exercise 3.1.25 from the same book.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer answers a different question than what was asked...**

The global dimension of a local ring $R$ coincides with the projective dimension of its residue field $R/\mathfrak m$. If the latter is finite, then the former is of course finite and it follows that the injective dimension of all modules is finite.

Comment: I am using the basic fact that the global dimension of a ring is simultaneously the supremum of the projective dimensions of its modules *and* the sumpremum of the injective dimension of its modules. This is proved in any textbook about homological algebra.

Comment: I think I don't get your hint. The residue field has finite injective dimension and I would like to prove that also its projective dimension is finite...

Comment: just to make sure I understand correctly: this answers the converse of the question asked, right?